# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition error

Tags: sql, select, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I don't know what I have done wrong here as I'm passing selecting to columns and inserting into a table with 2 columns so I don't understand what the error is talking about. I went to the line that the error is happing on and this is the code.

```
INSERT INTO #standardDefinitions1
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME as Column_Name FROM #standardDefinitions as SD
    SELECT CAST(ep.value as varchar(255)) AS Question FROM sys.extended_properties EP INNER JOIN sys.all_objects O ON ep.major_id = O.object_id INNER JOIN sys.schemas S on O.schema_id = S.schema_id INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON ep.major_id = c.object_id AND ep.minor_id = c.column_id
    WHERE o.name = 'Council'

CREATE TABLE #standardDefinitions1
(
    Column_Name VARCHAR(50),
    Question VARCHAR(255)
)
```

Can somone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: I think you are missing a `,` between your values?

Comment: I tried doing this before and it doesn't work :(

Comment: They should also be between `(...)`

Comment: @Amber Where would the brackets be placed?

Comment: `INSERT INTO #standardDefinitions1
    (SELECT COLUMN_NAME as Column_Name FROM #standardDefinitions as SD, 
    SELECT CAST(ep.value as varchar(255)) AS Question FROM sys.extended_properties EP ...joins ommitted...  )
    WHERE o.name = 'Council'` Assuming both selects only return one value

Comment: @Amber no they both return more than 1 value and also when i add the brackets the SELECT statements show 'Incorrect Syntax'

Comment: if you want to do a batch insert you need to do a single select statement that selects two values.

Comment: @Amber There from different tables and i cant do a JOIN as there is nothing the same from both tables. Is there no way around doing 2 SELECT statements in 1 INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

You should join both selects like that

```
INSERT INTO #standardDefinitions1
SELECT SD.COLUMN_NAME as Column_Name, CAST(ep.value as varchar(255)) AS Question
FROM #standardDefinitions as SD
    INNER JOIN sys.extended_properties EP 
    INNER JOIN sys.all_objects O ON ep.major_id = O.object_id 
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas S on O.schema_id = S.schema_id 
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON ep.major_id = c.object_id AND ep.minor_id = c.column_id
WHERE o.name = 'Council'
```

You can do a full join without condition, it's called cartesian join, it joins every row of table 1 with every row of table 2. Which is what, I guess, you were up to.